# Firebase webpack showing error "ReferenceError:fetch is not defined"

Tags: firebase, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have faced some problems that is throwing error of "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined", when trying to build angular universal ssr with firebase.

Error:

> ```
> > /Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:267054
> > registerFunctions(_firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"],
> > fetch.bind(self));
> >                                                                          ^
> > 
> > ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
> >     at Module.<anonymous> (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:267054:74)
> >     at __webpack_require__ (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:26:30)
> >     at Module.<anonymous> (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:265886:77)
> >     at __webpack_require__ (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:26:30)
> >     at Object.firebase (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:154095:18)
> >     at __webpack_require__ (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:151524:30)
> >     at Object../src/app/auth.service.ts (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:152588:18)
> >     at __webpack_require__ (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:151524:30)
> >     at Object../src/app/home/desktop-home.component.ngfactory.js (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:152882:33)
> >     at __webpack_require__ (/Users/ooicw/Minimum_reproducible_example/dist/server.js:151524:30)
> > npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! roomer-app@0.0.0
> > serve:ssr: `node dist/server` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm
> > ERR! Failed at the roomer-app@0.0.0 serve:ssr script. npm ERR! This is
> > probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
> > output above.
> > 
> > npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> > /Users/ooicw/.npm/_logs/2021-03-27T05_12_14_383Z-debug.log
> ```

This issue happened when I upgraded the firebase and @angular/fire version:

```
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.4"
"firebase": "^7.24.0"
```

Is there anyone that has faced similar problems or any advice/workarounds for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" Also: please don't post pictures of textual content. Instead post the content as plain text, and use the formatting features of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.

Comment: Hey @Jay, you are right, I didn't consider that image has these drawbacks. I have edited the questions, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error, I have managed to solve it by excluding the firebase node modules as there are multiple node modules in the project.

Here's some workarounds provided by Firebase engineers:

[Similar case for SSR using Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1455#issuecomment-455712500)

[Some options to resolve the issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1797#issuecomment-498474850)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this ticket after Firebase released v9+ modular version:
in Gatsbyjs, I've fixed this problem by specifying the following in the webpack configuration:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
  stage,
  rules,
  loaders,
  plugins,
  actions,
}) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      fallback: { "util": false },
      alias: {
        ['firebase/app']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['firebase/auth']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['firebase/firestore']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['firebase/storage']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/storage/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['@firebase/storage']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['firebase/functions']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/functions/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['@firebase/functions']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@firebase/functions/dist/index.node.cjs.js'),
        ['firebase/performance']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/performance/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['@firebase/performance']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@firebase/performance/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['firebase/analytics']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/analytics/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['@firebase/analytics']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['@firebase/installations']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@firebase/installations/dist/index.cjs.js'),
        ['idb']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/idb/lib/node.js'),
      },
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
  })
}
```